# convert image to byte[] c# and get image back in android

Tags: c#, java, android

I have the following code in c# which convert image to the byte[]

```
MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

now i want to get the image back in the android, what should i do ?

Comment: in Android? you mean using JAVA?

Comment: where exactly have u used this piece of code? in android? or any server?

Comment: what is this??? C# Android - MonoDroid, you mean?

Comment: server is c# sending image to the android, but i cant get the image out

Answer (score 2):

Im not really sure what your problem is as you haven't answered anyones question but if you just want to make a bitmap out of a byte array this how to do it

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, opt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert ByteArray to Base64 string in C#. Then Convert Base64 string to ByteArray in android an do everything you want. In this method you can work with any object type in addition to bitmap.

Comment: How to BitmapFactory.decodeStream(~Java) write into c#? I want Image in ARGB_8888 Format Do you have any idea? [moreinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68174153/convert-java-code-of-bitmap-into-c-sharp-code-in-console-app/68174469?noredirect=1#comment120495113_68174469)