# Convert Java Code of Bitmap into C# code In Console app

Tags: java, c#, bitmap, console-application, bitmapfactory

I am trying to convert Java code into c#
So here is Java code

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 1;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap decodeStream = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(openInputStream, null, options);
```

Then I am saving this bitmap by

```
File appDirectory= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File dest = new File(appDirectory, "yourImage.jpg");


    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest)) {
        decodeStream.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now can anyone help me to convert this code into c#. I Tried to import Xamrine Android DLL but got success no far.
I am

Comment: _"I Tried to import Xamrine Android DLL"_ - why? Please share your best shot at C# code you have.

Comment: Also this comment `// PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored` makes no sense if your are saving to JPG?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you only need to load simple jpg image. That is all your java code do.

If you want to load jpg image from stream you can use

```
Bitmap.FromStream()
```

e.g.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"Image Address.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var decodeStream = Bitmap.FromStream(fs);
}
```

of course you can open your image without stream too.

```
var image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"Image Address.jpg");
```

So your code will be something like this

```
File appDirectory= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
File dest = new File(appDirectory, "yourImage.jpg");
var image = Bitmap.FromFile(dest.FullName);
```

You can not access Bitmap class out of the box.

For dot net core install package System.Drawing.Common.

For dot net framework add reference to System.Drawing.

For Xamarin see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34869330/5964792

Comment: Actually something is happening at this line  "options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;"  where bitmap is configure to this texture. 
So that's something I am looking in c#.

Comment: @MayurAsodariya ARGB_8888 means use 8 bits for alpha, red, green and blue channels. In jpg you don't have alpha channel and all these info usually exist in image header. This config is usually necessary when you enter raw image not jpg or png. That's why it has preferred in it's name.